# C++ Sending a private class variable into a function

Tags: c++, class, private

I'm writing a program dealing with binary search trees in C++. I'm using a .h file that contains a class "treeNode" and I have a function that searches the tree for a specific number and returns a boolean as to whether the number was found or not.  My problem is that I have a private class variable for the "treeNode" class called "root" that is a pointer and points to the first element within the tree.  I need to somehow send that variable into the search function from the .cpp file as a function parameter.

How do I do this? Every time I try, I get an error telling me that it's a private class variable.  Classes confuse me a little.

Thanks!

Comment: If the search function is the class member, why do you need to pass the root variable as argument?

Comment: i guess i would need another way to do it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this skeleton and build your classes.

```
class treeNode
{
private:
    int data;
};

class tree
{
private:
    treeNode* root;

public:
    bool search(int data)
    {
    //root is accessible here. No need to pass as argument
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a private variable is to be able to hide that variable/function/etc from anything besides the current class that you are working in. Even derived classes may not access the private variable. If you make the search function a member function of the class in which tree was stored then you would be able to access it. If you want to access it outside of the class then create a function that returns it.

P.S. If you post your code here you may gain some helpful insight as to how design your code better.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a function that searches the tree for a specific number

Is your function part of the class that has your private variable?